# How to assign a div class to a echo function

Tags: functions

How can I assign a CSS (span or div) class to this function, so that I can style the output in my style sheet?

```
function show_today_date() {
    echo date(get_option('date_format'));
}
add_shortcode( 'showtodaydate', 'show_today_date' );
```

The result is **15 October, 2014**. Now I wish to style the output, which won't be possible if I do not have a CSS element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a specific WordPress question, is a topic in php coding.

You can add html markup inside the echo in your function, like the follow example:

```
function show_today_date() {

    echo '<div class="example">' . date( get_option( 'date_format' ) ) . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'showtodaydate', 'show_today_date' );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. It perfectly worked. Sorry I placed that in the wrong forum. Will take care next time.

Comment: The context is WordPress, only the problem is PHP coding. Please check the flag, the stick left, on the answer, if is the right answer.